# Uniqid returning similar value every time

Tags: php

I'm generating a 5 letter uniqid in PHP this way:

```
$id = substr(uniqid(),0,5);
```

And every single time I call it, I get the value `5004b`. Why is that happening?

If I remove the `substr`, the `5004b` part stays constant while the remaining changes. Isn't this severely reducing the entropy of the GUID being generated?

Comment: I'm not sure how `uniqid` works exactly, but it is based on microtime, so if the beginning remains the same for a longer period, the end is very likely to repeat itself. So I think you should use the complete result of `uniqid` or find something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

uniqid() is based on microtime(), the beginning is going to be the same for a long time.

My suggestion is that you just increment every time or something if you need a 5 digit long uniqid.

Comment: It's true, this would give you a perfect guarantee of no collisions.

Comment: But I need them to be non-sequential so users cannot guess them.

Comment: @xbonez there are easy ways to obfuscate incremented ids, check out [this link](http://mynikko.blogspot.com/2012/03/auto-increment-id-obfuscation.html) (first result in google).

Comment: @AlexLunix: Thanks for the link. I ended up going with what I posted under Kolink's answer.

Answer (score 3):

`uniqid()` only works if you take the full value. It would make more sense to take the last five characters rather than the first:

```
$id = substr(uniqid(),-5);
```

However, after just one second you'll get repeating values. You really should just take the full `uniqid()`.

Comment: I see your point. Even going for the last 5 will give repeats. How can I get a random sequence of 5 alphanumeric letters, like imgur does? I'm not worried about clashes since everytime I issue a new ID, I check it against the database for any collisions.

Comment: Ok, found a way to do it. I'll create a string of all letters and can then use `substr()` and `str_shuffle`.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the entropy of the output, you can use `uniqid('', true);`. According to the doc, this "will add additional entropy (using the combined linear congruential generator) at the end of the return value, which increases the likelihood that the result will be unique."

Comment: But that doesn't help if you're only taking the first five characters, as the OP is doing.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol is right. It will just append some more numbers at the end of the string, but OP was using the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a unique ID, don't use uniqid() as it only returns the an ID based on the current time. If your computer is fast enough, it will produce the same values again and again.

Enlarging the entropy (by passing "true" as the second argument) helps, but it cannot hide the fact that this function is flawed, and should not be used more than once in a script.

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like substr(uniqid(rand(),1),0,7). this generates unique ids from a random seed. then again if you are saving them to a database you may need to check whether they exist before generating again. Do something like:

```
function idExists($id){
//query database and check if the id already exists
}
//then use this to generate
$id=null;
   do{
$id=substr(uniqid(rand(),1),0,7); 
}while(idExists($id));
//then you get your unique id here
```